# Discord.js Music Bot: How do I make one command that adds a whole playlist of songs into the queue

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, discord.js

I'm on Windows 10 and using Node.js

I used this YouTube video to get most of the code (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0lsD7U0JSI&t=1184s).
After watching the video, I wanted to add a few commands on my own, so using the code from the video I made the "christmas" command, where I can add a ton of songs to the queue without having to input the command one by one. The command works well, but my problem is that if I try to add another song onto the queue using the "play" command, it just ignores the play command and stops at the end of the christmas queue. So my question is, is there a better way to write my "christmas" command?

[Code]

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

const PREFIX = "&";

const queue = new Map();

var servers = {};

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Logged in as ' + client.user.tag + '!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'play':

            function play(connection, message){
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    
                server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0],{filter: "audio"}));
    
    
    
                server.dispatcher.on("finish", function(){
                   server.queue.shift();
                   if(server.queue[0]){
                       play(connection, message);
                   }else {
                       connection.disconnect();
                   }
                })
    
            }         
        
            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send("cant do that");
                return;
            }
            
            if(!message.member.voice.channel){
                message.channel.send("go into vc");
                return;
            }

            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            }
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.guild.voice.connection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            })
        break;

        case 'skip':
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];
            if(server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
            message.channel.send("this song sucks ima skip");
        break;

        case 'stop':
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];
            if(message.guild.voice.connection){
                for(var i = server.queue.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
                    server.queue.splice(i,1);
                }

                server.dispatcher.end();
                message.channel.send("k bye")
                console.log('stopped the queue');
            }

            if(message.guild.connection) message.guild.voice.connection.disconnect();
        break;

        case 'christmas':
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];
            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeLfuIzF6v8", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yhI35F2NB0", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfF10ow4YEo",
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnXxxKZ57Tw", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IHP9Acxa54", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0ajuTaHBtM", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-OnZ55bZ3U",
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRyhqobl0sk", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHzeTKPlbJg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfZPtkqXQIA", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-HR0e4gLzQ",
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJvGf_ifiKw", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AN_R4pR1hck", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJ5DOWPGxwg", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dkq3LD-4pmM", 
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgR3dpfun68", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvU07SwKM2U", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAbRtgo7sVo", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihW56Xa3XGQ",
                "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFNtuHEUexI"]
            }
            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            })
        break;
    }
});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

I am fairly new to coding in javascript, and this is my first time submitting a question on StackOverflow, so sorry if there is a few problems with formatting. If there is anything else that I didn't put in here that you guys need, please let me know. Thanks!